# How to get the e-mail addresses in the CC field?

Tags: vba, outlook

I found code in [How to get the sender’s email address from one or more emails in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/7047-outlook-vba-get-sender-email-address.html).

I need to get the e-mail addresses of the CC field as well.

```vb
Sub GetSmtpAddressOfSelectionEmail()
  Dim xExplorer As Explorer
  Dim xSelection As Selection
  Dim xItem As Object
  Dim xMail As MailItem
  Dim xAddress As String
  Dim xFldObj As Object
  Dim FilePath As String
  Dim xFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
  On Error Resume Next
  Set xExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
  Set xSelection = xExplorer.Selection
  For Each xItem In xSelection
    If xItem.Class = olMail Then
      Set xMail = xItem
      xAddress = xAddress & VBA.vbCrLf & "  " & GetSmtpAddress(xMail)
    End If
  Next
  If MsgBox("Sender SMTP Address is: " & xAddress & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to export the address list to a txt file? ", vbYesNo, "Kutools for Outlook") = vbYes Then
    Set xFldObj = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseforFolder(0, "Select a Folder", 0, 16)
    Set xFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If xFldObj Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    FilePath = xFldObj.Items.Item.Path & "\Address.txt"
    Close #1
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Sender SMTP Address is: " & xAddress
    Close #1
    Set xFSO = Nothing
    Set xFldObj = Nothing
    MsgBox "Address list has been exported to：" & FilePath, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Kutools for Outlook"
  End If
End Sub

Function GetSmtpAddress(Mail As MailItem)
  Dim xNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim xEntryID As String
  Dim xAddressEntry As AddressEntry
  Dim PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID As String
  Dim PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String
  Dim xExchangeUser As exchangeUser
  On Error Resume Next
  GetSmtpAddress = ""
  Set xNameSpace = Application.Session
  If Mail.sender.Type <> "EX" Then
    GetSmtpAddress = Mail.sender.Address
  Else
    PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102"
    xEntryID = Mail.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(Mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID))
    Set xAddressEntry = xNameSpace.GetAddressEntryFromID(xEntryID)
    If xAddressEntry Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If xAddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Or xAddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry Then
      Set xExchangeUser = xAddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
      If xExchangeUser Is Nothing Then Exit Function
      GetSmtpAddress = xExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
      PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
      GetSmtpAddress = xAddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

How could I adapt the code to include the e-mail addresses from the CC field as well?

I tried setting Recipients but couldn't get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `GetSmtpAddress` function with your own where you could get the `CC` recipients in the following way (a raw sketch):

```
Function GetSmtpAddress(Mail As MailItem) as String
  Dim emailAddress as String
  Dim recipient as Outlook.Recipient
  Dim recipients as Outlook.Recipients
  Set recipients = Mail.Recipients 
  For Each recipient In recipients
    If recipient.Type = olCC Then
      If recipient.AddressEntry.Type = "EX" Then
        emailAddress = emailAddress & " " & recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
      Else
        emailAddress = emailAddress & " " & recipient.Address
      End If
    End If
  Next
  Return emailAddress 
End Function
```

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all recipients in the `MailItem.Recipients` collection, check that `Recipient.Type = olCC`. For each `Recipient` object use `Recipient.Address`. Note that you can end up with `EX` type addresses (instead of `SMTP`). Check that `Recipient.AddressEntry.Type` is `"SMTP"`. If it is not, use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress` instead (do check for nulls).